# Using an ERE Pattern File for a grep Inversion Search

Tags: bash, grep

I need to use regex patterns in a grep pattern file (ERE) as BRE is insufficient.
If data file contains:

```
alpha 1
bravo 1
gamma 1
delta 1
omicron 1
sigma 1
alpha 2
bravo 2
gamma 2
delta 2
```

and the grep inversion pattern file contains:

```
alpha
bravo
gamma
delta
```

then the following grep inversion:
`$ grep -v -f pattern_file main_file`
produces

```
omicron 1
sigma 1
```

This is the desired BRE output. But I need to tune the pattern file ERE so that the keywords stipulate *beginning of line+keyword+space* with the pattern file entries defined as:

```
"^alpha "
"^bravo "
"^gamma "
"^delta "
```

What is the correct grep inversion to produce the same two record output?
The following does not work:
`$ grep -E -v -f pattern_file main_file`

Comment: Do you REALLY want to know how to use grep for this (which would be fragile and inefficient and involve calling other tools too) or how you should really do this using Unix tools (e.g. 1 robust, efficient call to awk)?

Comment: I don't understand why BREs are insufficient for this particular task. The `^` anchor is part of BRE. You may be confusing BREs with fixed strings (`-F` option of `grep`).

Comment: I'd go with an awk solution if you have it. I'm not married to grep for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the pattern file set as originally posted, a solution has been found that uses only a single grep inversion on an array loaded with the keywords from the `main_file`. No additional *nix tools used.
[Organizing ".bash_history" into ".bash_history.cmd" category files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75507491/organizing-bash-history-into-bash-history-cmd-category-files)

```
declare -a keywords
keywords=(alpha bravo gamma delta)
IFS=\|; grep -E -v "^(${keywords[*]}) " main_file
```

which produces:

```
omicron 1
sigma 1
```

This satisfies the *beginning of line* anchor requirement as well as the space after the keyword, using an alternative token `|` to account for `{keywords[*]}` expansion, separated by the IFS character.

Comment: Well, where do you read the file that contains the regexps? If you can hardcode them in the script then you don't even need an array: `grep -E -v '^(alpha|bravo|gamma|delta) ' main_file`

Comment: Fravadona If I understand your question, I am using a `load_categories` function of the sort: `readarray -t categories < <(sed -e '/^$/d' -e '/^\s*[@#]/ d' "$CATEGORIES_FILE")` which is then used in the `main` extraction loop to select out the records needed and then the inversion grep `IFS=\|; grep -E -v "^(${categories[*]})` is done on the `main_file` to compress it.

Comment: Fravadona The `keywords` and `categories` are synomymous for the array here. The `$CATEGORIES_FILE` contains the keywords that were once hard-coded to the `keywords` array which are now read in, making the extractions flexible. Sorry, I've cut/paste from the production script instead of the test suite now that it's working. Blank lines and comments `[@#]` are ignored during the read.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a bash process substitution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

grep -E -v -f <(sed 's/.*/^& /' pattern_file) main_file
```

<sup>**warning:** If the `pattern_file` contains ERE special characters that you want to be treated as literals then you'll have to escape them.</sup>

or `awk`:

```bash
awk 'FNR == NR {arr[$0]; next} !($1 in arr)' pattern_file main_file
```

<sup>**remark:** the behavior is a little different here; for example `gamma 1` and     `gamma 1` will both be excluded by `awk`.</sup>

Comment: ^1 for the awk answer. It's also worth mentioning that given input like `foo.bar` in `pattern_file` the awk script would match exactly and only that in `main_file` while the `grep+sed+shell process substituion` shell script version would also match `foodbar`, etc. which would probably be undesirable.

Comment: Neither the process substitution grep nor the awk solution works here. When `pattern_file` contains the BRE patterns: ```delta 1
omicron 1
sigma 1
delta 2
``` is the output; there should be no `delta` here. And when the ERE patterns are used, the output is all 10 records, so nothing was filtered. Both approaches yield the same output. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for reminder; I added a warning for it

Comment: @Paul_Capo the awk only test the first word of each line; if your "patterns" contain multiple "columns" then you cannot use the current code. On the other hand, the grep should work. Does `grep $'\r' pattern_file main_file` outputs something?